# How to get QThreads to work in a console PySide program?

Tags: python, multithreading, qt, pyside

I'm trying to learn how to use threading in a python program. I'm using PySide and QThreads since I'm going to implement gui afterwards with PySide.

I have understood the main consept of threading, at least I think. But I'm still confused with event loops. And I think that is the problem with my aplication.

Here is a sample application that I can't get to work properly.
In my main class I have several worker threads and I want to them to report their progress to the main main class. But the main program don't print progress messages in real time.

How could I get this to work?

```
from PySide import QtCore
import time, sys

class MyWorkerThread(QtCore.QThread):
    message = QtCore.Signal(str)

    def __init__(self, id, parent=None):
        super(MyWorkerThread, self).__init__(parent)
        self.id = id

    def run(self):
        for i in range(10):
            self.message.emit("%d: %d" % (self.id, i))
            time.sleep(0.2)

class MainProgram():
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        self.threads = []

        self.addWorker(MyWorkerThread(1))
        self.addWorker(MyWorkerThread(2))

    def addWorker(self, worker):
        worker.message.connect(self.printMessage, QtCore.Qt.QueuedConnection)
        self.threads.append(worker)

    def startWorkers(self):
        for worker in self.threads:
            worker.start()
            worker.wait()
        self.workersFinished()

    def workersFinished(self):
        QtCore.QCoreApplication.instance().quit()

    @QtCore.Slot(str)
    def printMessage(self, text):
        sys.stdout.write(text+'\n')
        sys.stdout.flush()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtCore.QCoreApplication(sys.argv)
    m = MainProgram()
    m.startWorkers()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: What do you mean in real time ?. And you have should start all thread before calling `wait()`. You're starting one, wait for it to complete then start the next one.

Comment: The program don't print anything during the working loop. But it prints all the messages at the same time after both threads are complete. And after this the program don't close itself. I'm going to have few hundred these workers and their process is pretty intensive. So actually I don't even want those to run parallel in this point. Maybe later I'll change this so few threads runs parallel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`worker.wait()` is the problem. This call blocks the main thread (in this case the one running event loop) until the worker finishes its job.

Here is a slightly changed version (I've commented my changes):

```
from PySide import QtCore
import time, sys

class MyWorkerThread(QtCore.QThread):
    message = QtCore.Signal(str)

    def __init__(self, id, parent=None):
        super(MyWorkerThread, self).__init__(parent)
        self.id = id

    def run(self):
        for i in range(10):
            self.message.emit("%d: %d" % (self.id, i))
            time.sleep(0.2)

class MainProgram():
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        self.threads = []

        self.addWorker(MyWorkerThread(1))
        self.addWorker(MyWorkerThread(2))

    def addWorker(self, worker):
        worker.message.connect(self.printMessage, QtCore.Qt.QueuedConnection)
        # connect the finished signal to method so that we are notified
        worker.finished.connect(self.workersFinished)
        self.threads.append(worker)

    def startWorkers(self):
        for worker in self.threads:
            worker.start()
            # no wait, no finished. you start the threads and leave.

    def workersFinished(self):
        if all(worker.isFinished() for worker in self.threads):
            # wait until all the threads finished
            QtCore.QCoreApplication.instance().quit()

    @QtCore.Slot(str)
    def printMessage(self, text):
        sys.stdout.write(text+'\n')
        sys.stdout.flush()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtCore.QCoreApplication(sys.argv)
    m = MainProgram()
    m.startWorkers()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks, that was a great help.