# gui locked when calling QWebView.print_()

Tags: python, qt, pdf-generation, pyside, qwebview

I'm working with **Python 2.7** and **PySide**, and i need to export a big html-file to a pdf-file.

I have tried loading it with a `QWebView` and then printing it to a `QPrinter` configured for pdf-format. this works fine.

However, there is one big problem with my solution: when I call `QWebView.print_()`, the gui is locked up, and for windows it looks like my program has crashed. This happens because of the big size of my html (1000 pages and more).

So my question is: is there a clean way to avoid this 'crash' ?

EDIT:

I tried to do the printing in a separate thread, like jadkik94 suggested.
As far as I understand the code below should work. Unfortunately it crashes randomly. ;)
Any ideas why this is the case?

```
import sys
from PySide import QtGui, QtWebKit, QtCore

class PrintThread(QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self, webview, printer, parent=None):
        super(PrintThread, self).__init__(parent)
        self._webview = webview
        self._printer = printer

    def run(self):
        self._webview.print_(self._printer)

class MyWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWindow,self).__init__()

        # a printer to print on
        self._myPrinter = QtGui.QPrinter()
        self._myPrinter.setOutputFormat(QtGui.QPrinter.PdfFormat)
        self._myPrinter.setPrintRange(QtGui.QPrinter.AllPages)
        self._myPrinter.setOrientation(QtGui.QPrinter.Portrait)
        self._myPrinter.setPaperSize(QtGui.QPrinter.A4)
        self._myPrinter.setNumCopies(1)

        # a webview for loading the html and printing it
        self._webview = QtWebKit.QWebView(self)
        self.setCentralWidget( self._webview )
        self._webview.loadFinished.connect(self.webViewLoadFinished)

        # print-preview-dialog
        self._previewDlg = QtGui.QPrintPreviewDialog(self._myPrinter)
        #self._previewDlg.paintRequested.connect(self.dlgPaintRequestNoThread) # works but freezes the mainthread
        self._previewDlg.paintRequested.connect(self.dlgPaintRequestWithThread) # as far is i understand this should work... but crashes randomly ;)

        # load the html
        self._webview.load('index.htm') # file is 2MB

    def webViewLoadFinished(self):
        # when webview has finished loading, show the dialog
        self._previewDlg.show()

    def dlgPaintRequestNoThread(self):
        self._webview.print_(self._myPrinter)

    def dlgPaintRequestWithThread(self):
        self.printPages()

        # wait for the print-thread to finish without blocking the mainthread
        eventLoop =  QtCore.QEventLoop()
        self.worker.finished.connect(eventLoop.quit)
        eventLoop.exec_()

    def printPages(self):
        self.worker = PrintThread(self._webview, self._myPrinter)
        self.worker.finished.connect(self.donePrinting)

        self.progressDlg = QtGui.QProgressDialog()
        self.progressDlg.setCancelButton(None)
        self.progressDlg.show()

        self.worker.start()

    def donePrinting(self):
        self.progressDlg.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need to use threads to solve this problem. It appears that `QWebView.print_()` runs in the main thread, and thus blocks your GUI from running.

You have 2 options, you either use Python's `threading` module or Qt's `QThread`s.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10044197/how-to-get-qthreads-to-work-in-a-console-pyside-program) shows how you can use `QThread`s. Basically:

```
class PrintThread(QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self, webview, parent=None):
        super(PrintThread, self).__init__(parent)
        self.webview = webview

    def run(self):
        # Get a printer from somewhere
        self.webview.print_(printer)
```

And then:

```
def printPage(self):
    worker = PrintThread(self.page)
    worker.finished.connect(self.donePrinting)
    # Show a loading dialog
    worker.start()

def donePrinting(self):
    # Close the loading dialog
    pass
```

You could apply the same thing with the threading module, but since you are already using pyside, why not use it for that too. Also, I am not sure if another thread (other than QThread) can mess with the Qt GUI, it might just tell you you cannot access the GUI thread from another thread (not sure though).

Comment: thank you for your help. so far this looks good, but how can i combine this with a QPrintPreviewWidget?
if i connect the previewWidget's paintRequested signal to a slot, where i start the QThread for printing, the preview does not update.
it works if i don't start a thread in the slot, but then blocks my gui again.
any ideas on how i can use the previewWidget with a thread that prints?

Comment: I can't help you this way... Either post it as another question or edit your post to include some code please. I think though that it shouldn't be very different though...